# How is the theme of innocence featured in the Turn of the Screw?

Tags: character-analysis, theme, henry-james, the-turn-of-the-screw

I noticed that in the novel *The Turn of the Screw* by Henry James, there is a theme of innocence. It's really shown through how the governess perceives Miles and Flora at first, but then as she realizes that they're being possessed by ghosts, but even after the governess notices that, she still somewhat perceives them as innocent. I'm not sure how else innocence is shown in *The Turn of the Screw* and what other moments to draw from in the text.